# What's the function of the "dephelp" libraries in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

When I installed OpenCV with brew, these libraries didn't come with the distribution. Same with macports. I can build them by making from source, but I wondered what they purpose do they serve if the standard distributions don't contain them.

Thanks in advance.